# How to drop multiple subtable from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am newbie in php-mysql. I have a table with Category and another table with subcategory. I create a separate table for each subcategory. When I try to delete a category , I need to drop all subcategory tables. But my subcategory table is not dropped. My code is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id2']))
{
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die ("error in connection");
$sel=mysql_select_db('category',$con);

$id=$_GET['id2'];
//echo $id;

$sql1="DELETE subcat FROM category INNER JOIN subcat  
WHERE category.id=subcat.id and category.id='$id'";
mysql_query($sql1);
$sql2 = "DELETE FROM category WHERE id='$id'";
mysql_query($sql2);

$da="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE id='$id'";
//print $da;
$data = mysql_query($da) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    $x = $row['sub'];
    $sql33="DROP TABLE $x";
    mysql_query($sql33) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $sql33;

}

header('location:category.php');
}
?>
```

Please advise what I am wrong with...

Thanks,
Sujith

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

First you delete the records from subcat and cat tables, then you try to retrive the subcat records again to drop the tables, which is obviously going to be an empty list. First obtain the list of tables, then delete the records and then drop the tables.

But honestly, you should not create and drop tables on the fly. This indicates bad database design in the first place!